# Overlay image into another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

if you could take a look for a moment at http://www.acehbus.com, you could see that the screenshot image of iPhone is fully seen in the screen. I want to know how to make the half of the image overlays the next div like in the http://sociali.st. I have tried z-index but it doesn't work. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got through your site, and I have two things:

1) dont use images with resolution of 649x1323. Half of that size will ok .. there are many of images of this phone, and people with slower connection will die on this. And it is still used only as smaller thumbs, so large resolutions are really not necessary.

2) You use the image as itself. Use div instead and give image as its background. See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8xhucpx8/

```
div.image{
  width:300px; 
height:200px;
background-image:url('http://www.acehbus.com/img/search.png');
background-position:top center; 
background-size:100% auto;    
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Haha I thought it too, bro. This is the version lame, I'll be working hard to make the next version. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :) If this answer suits you, plase, mark it as final answer. Also one more note: you can define the height :100% and min-height for example 200px. Then, if the text will be shorter than the image, the image will be 200px. If the text will be longer than the image, whole image will be shown. -in case you will preserve div structure you have now - new div will be in subcontainer of main div with text AND image.

Comment: and one more thing, if you look at the text of each screenshot, I don't know how to push the text vertically aligned even though I have tried vertical aligned middle, so I have to make a padding to 100-200px top from the text. The problem comes when it's viewed on mobile with lots space on top. How to vertically aligned, from your perspective? Should I have another div for text inside col-md-8 div? thanks!

Comment: for vertical-align, you have to have line-height defined first ... fut it is quite an alchemy to do it right .... experiment with values, but line-height is required for vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may always inspect a site with effect you want to achieve and try to apply it's approach in your project. The markup and styles are at direct access. If you noticed in the example you've provided the overlapping effect is achieved with combination of negative margins and absolute positioning. So if you play with these properties you gonna make it. I would go for something like this:

```
<div class="iphone"></div>

.iphone {
    bottom: -100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Look, I made some experiments and made [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1oxvgpjt/) fiddle

Comment: Cool, I love this idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `overflow: hidden` first give a fixed height to the `parent element` of the image in your case `col-md-6`. So do something like.

```css
.col-md-6 {
  height: 155px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="http://www.acehbus.com/img/search.png" alt="" width="200px" />
</div>
```